# How to Find Generating function of a sequence $\left\{\left(^9_n\right)\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty }$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I need to find Generating function of :

$$\left\{\left(^9_n\right)\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty }$$

$$\left\{n\left(^9_n\right)\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty }$$

my suggest answer for the first one:

$$A(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(^9_n\right)x^n=\sum _{n=0}^{9}\:\frac{9!}{n!\left(9-n\right)!}+0+0+0+...$$

so we get:

$$A(x)=\sum _{n=0}^9\:\left(^9_n\right)x^n=(1+x)^9$$

is my answer for the first one correct and any idea how to solve the second one ?

> the second one :
>
> $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum _{n=0}^9\:\left(^9_n\right)x^n\right)=\sum \:_{n=0}^9n\left(^9_n\right)x^{n-1}=9\left(1+x\right)^8$$
>
> multiply it with $x$, we get: $$\sum \:_{n=0}^9n\left(^9_n\right)x^n=9x\left(1+x\right)^8$$
>
> so for the second one $$B(x)=9x\left(1+x\right)^8$$

thanks

Comment: The conclusion is correct but the argument isn't. The factorial expression for $\dbinom nr$ is only valid for $0\leq r\leq n$. $\dbinom nr$ is _defined_ to be $0$ for $r\gt n$

Comment: For the second one, try differentiating the previous result wrt $x$.

Comment: oh so thats mean $A(x)=\left(^9_0\right)+\left(^9_1\right)x+\left(^9_2\right)x^2+...+\left(^9_9\right)x^9+0+0+...=\sum _{n=0}^9\:\left(^9_n\right)x^n$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas okey i got it thanks alot

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now, did you get the second one?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas yes for the second one : $=\sum \:_{n=0}^9\:n\cdot \:\left(^9_n\right)x^{n-1}=9\left(1+x\right)^8\rightarrow \sum _{n=0}^9\:n\cdot \left(^9_n\right)x^n=9x\left(1+x\right)^8$